# iPhone JSF creating sessionscope bean every page navigation

Tags: java, iphone, jsf, javabeans, ajax4jsf

I have an AuthenticationBean that handles user logins and access rights. It works perfectly fine on Desktops, iPads and Playbooks. The problem is when I have an iPhone that tries to login, the navigation state becomes null, and the authentication bean is recreated.

The bean is set to be SessionScoped, and the State is saved on the client. Any idea what might be causing the navigationstate to become null, or why the bean is being recreated everytime I try to access a page.

Developed on JSF 2.0 + RichFaces 4.1

Comment: Session is backed by a cookie. Apparently the particular iPhone browser has cookies disabled.